# Go Channel - My code looks overwriting channels but works.

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I just started learning Go recently and I was confused when I learning Goroutine. 
Here's my code. This intends to finish 3 processes concurrently.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func wait1(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    log.Print("waited 1 sec")
    c <- "wait1 finished\n"

}

func wait2(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    log.Print("waited 2 sec")
    c <- "wait2 finished\n"
}

func wait3(c chan string) {
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    log.Print("waited 3 sec")
    c <- "wait3 finished\n"
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 3)
    log.Print("started")
    go wait1(c)
    go wait2(c)
    go wait3(c)
    w1, w2, w3 := <-c, <-c, <-c
    log.Print("finished")
    fmt.Println(w1, w2, w3)
}
```

For me, this part looks inputting different functions into the same channel called c and trying to print the values received from c.

```
c := make(chan string, 3)
log.Print("started")
go wait1(c)
go wait2(c)
go wait3(c)
w1, w2, w3 := <-c, <-c, <-c
log.Print("finished")
fmt.Println(w1, w2, w3)
```

However, as you can see, output is what I expected. It processes 3 functions at the same time and returns "finished" statement.

```
2015/11/25 09:41:31 started
2015/11/25 09:41:32 waited 1 sec
2015/11/25 09:41:33 waited 2 sec
2015/11/25 09:41:34 waited 3 sec
2015/11/25 09:41:34 finished
wait1 finished
wait2 finished
wait3 finished
```

Why it's unnecessary to create 3 different channels like c1, c2, c3...?
Why value is not overwritten even though I'm using the same channel called c?

Comment: A channel is like a conveyor belt. When you're doing things like `c <- "wait3 finished\n"` you're not storing that "as" a channel... you're sending it _down_ a channel. Imagine it literally like a conveyor belt that you have workers putting strings of text on. One after the other they are sent down the belt and plucked off at the end when you receive them (the `<-c, <-c, <-c` part does this).

Comment: In addition to the above... perhaps this image makes it clearer for you? http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GkVAtGeUzrs/UwIQ6AezJmI/AAAAAAAANYE/5XWpxN-zA3w/s1600/Screen+Shot+2014-02-17+at+8.38.15+AM.png

Comment: Simon, I really love your picture and metaphor to conveyor belt. I've been thinking that Go has created 3 different conveyor belt called "c". Looks it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you view channels as a variable. A variable that can hold some value. So if there was some `value1` and you wrote another `value2` you basically expect the `value1` to disappear. Which is wrong.

Try to take a look at the channels as a buffer or a priority queue (some people find it crude comparison). Channel has it's size (your third variable `3`) which tells how many values can be simultaneously in it. Once you put something in the channel, you can view it as being processes with the priority equal to amount of time needed to finish this go-routine.

So in your case you put 3 elements in your priority queue with `go wait()` and then extracted from a queue with `w1, w2, w3 := <-c, <-c, <-c`. So nothing gets overwritten.

Comment: Actually, I'd rather compare a channel to a [named pipe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe): it has name, by which you can use it, it **is** a FIFO (no real priorities, first come, first serve) and once a value is read from it, it is removed from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Unbuffered channels sync before sending data through.  So in this case, your successive calls to `<-c` in your assignment line block until the wait functions on the other end sends something through.

Markus makes an excellent point though and it should be pointed out that this `w1, w2, w3 := <-c, <-c, <-c` only works because you've staggered the wait times for your different wait functions.  If those functions waited an arbitrary amount of time before sending data on the channel, you would not have any guarantee that w2 gets assigned to the result sent from wait2.  It would just be set to which ever value was the second value sent through the channel.